# Installing Kivy 1.10.1 on Raspbian Buster

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, kivy

I found errors when installing kivy 1.10.1.dev0 on my new Raspberry Pi 4.

The source of error comes from the instruction:

```
sudo pip3 install git+https://github.com/kivy/kivy.git@master
```

after following the guide https://kivy.readthedocs.io/en/master/installation/installation-rpi.html#. 
It gives the error:

```
  building 'kivy.lib.vidcore_lite.egl' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.7/tmp/pip-req-build-bsrs6yn7/kivy/lib/vidcore_lite
  arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/tmp/pip-req-build-bsrs6yn7/kivy/include -I/opt/vc/include -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vmcs_host/linux -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c /tmp/pip-req-build-bsrs6yn7/kivy/lib/vidcore_lite/egl.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.7/tmp/pip-req-build-bsrs6yn7/kivy/lib/vidcore_lite/egl.o
  /tmp/pip-req-build-bsrs6yn7/kivy/lib/vidcore_lite/egl.c:1:2: error: #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
   #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
    ^~~~~
   error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for Kivy
  Running setup.py clean for Kivy
Failed to build Kivy
Installing collected packages: Kivy
```